# URL in UIWebView containing JSON object shown as [Object%20Object]

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to access a JSON object in a URL inside the UIWebView. Here is my code for that -

```
func webView(myWebView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        let requestUrl:NSURL = request.URL!

        let url:String = requestUrl.absoluteString

        if url.rangeOfString("token") != nil {
            print("exists")
            let index = url.rangeOfString("token=", options: .BackwardsSearch)?.endIndex

            let tokenValue = url.substringFromIndex(index!)

            if let data = tokenValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                do {
                    let json: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                    print(json)
                } catch {
                    print("Something went wrong")
                }
            }
            self.tokenField.text = "\(tokenValue)"
        }
```

The 'request URL' is coming from the following JS -

```
var tokenObj = {"accessToken":"abc123"};
window.location.href = "didtap://LoginButton?token=" + tokenObj;
```

The problem here is when I am trying to access the JSON Object using Swift, I see the URL coming in as `didtap://LoginButton?token=[object%20Object]`

Here is also a screenshot of my debugger.

I am looking for the JSON object as is, so I can use the token back in my app where needed.
[image]

Comment: That's the percent escaped url. It should not cause any problem to access the resource.

Comment: @FahriAzimov, that's what I understand but am not able to access the value, is there something wrong in my JSONSerialization?

Comment: Also, after I convert the request URL to string, the object is shown as %5Bobject%20Object%5D. Does that mean, the object is not accessible as an object anymore? If so, how can I access the object without converting the url to a string?

Comment: No, something wrong with JS, it's sending the wrong JSON. `[object Object]` is not right JSON.

Comment: this is my json object with single key value pair {"accessToken":"abc123"}

Comment: But in url it's coming as `[object Object]`, not like you are describing, check your JS code. And why not send your token as regular param? Why do you use JSON for that, it's really weird.

Comment: You can use **substring.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding** will solve your problem

Comment: @PKT: This helped me! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substring.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding will solve your problem